# how to `git ls-files` for just one directory level.

Tags: git, ls, glob

I'm using msysgit (1.7.9), and I'm looking for the right invocation of the `git ls-files` command to show just the (tracked) files and directories at the current level, either from the index, or the current working directory if that's easier.

Essentially it would give a directory listing similar that that you would see on Github. Coming from Windows, I'm not too familiar with the right way of doing the globbing(?).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(late edit for a feature added in Git 1.8.5, after the question and answer were written:)

Git's [pathspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) ordinarily match `*` with any path substring, including `/` separators, but you can use shell pathname-matching conventions by adding a magic `:(glob)` prefix. So to list just the files in the current directory,

```
git ls-files ':(glob)*'   # just the files in the current directory
git ls-files ':(glob)test/*' # and so on
```

As a side note, you can do many more things with those magic prefixes, [chase that link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

You can also turn on shell-style globbing with the `--glob-pathspecs` option on the Git command itself, so

```
$ alias ggit='git --glob-pathspecs'
$ # and a personal favorite:
$ git config --global alias.ls 'ls-files --exclude-standard'
$ # then whenever
$ ggit ls '*'     # note the quoting to bypass the shell's globbing,
```

---

Original answer, still works:

I think you want `git ls-tree HEAD` sed'd to taste.  The second word of ls-tree's output will be `tree` for directories, `blob` for files, `commit` for submodules, the filename is everything after the ascii tab.

Edit: adapting from [@iegik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452962/how-to-git-ls-files-for-just-one-directory-level/10456380#comment64472316_10456380) and to better fit the question as asked,

```
git ls-files . | sed s,/.*,/, | uniq
```

will list the indexed files starting at the current level and collapse directories to their first component.

Further edit: another way to do it is

```
git ls-tree `git write-tree` .
```

and you can use `git ls-tree`'s options for some nice seasoning.

Comment: `git ls-files | awk -F / '{print $1}' | uniq | xargs ls -dl --color=auto`

Comment: @iegik This is much better. I'd `sed s,/.*,,` instead of the awk, just 'cause it's shorter. Make this an answer, please? I'll bounty it.

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS — `ls: illegal option -- -`. I think you want, at least on macOS, `… | xargs 'ls' -Gdl` — someone else can check if that works on Linux, too?

Comment: Also, how to set this as a git alias? Non-shell aliases don't seem to support piping, but shell-aliases are run at the repository root, instead of the current directory (`git config --global alias.ls "\!git ls-files | awk -F / '{print $1}' | uniq | xargs 'ls' -Gdl"` is a start, but …)

Answer (score 23):

I believe `git ls-tree --name-only [branch]` will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's 95% the way there. Your `git ls-tree --name-only [branch]` lists both the directories and files in the same list (i.e. no trailing `/` for directories). I found `git ls-tree -d --name-only [branch]` will list just the directories. Part of the 'problem' is to spot submodule directories.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer! That, or it's a very good start towards one. :D

Comment: @PhilipOakley I was trying to do a similar thing, except with `git ls-files` rather than `git ls-tree`. With `git ls-files`, it looks like the equivalent option is `--directory` ( in that command, `-d` is short for `--deleted`).

Answer (score 7):

To just list the files in the current working directory that are tracked by git, I found that the following is several times faster than using `git ls-tree...`:

```
ls | grep -f <(git ls-files)
```

It would take a little messing around with sed if you also wanted to include directories, something along the lines of:

```
ls | grep -f <(git ls-files | sed 's/\/.*//g' | sort | uniq)
```

assuming you don't have any '/' characters in the names of your files. As well as...

`ls -a | grep -f <(git ls-files | sed 's/\/.*//g' | sort | uniq)`

in order to also list "invisible" (yet-tracked) files.

Comment: This is nice... I wonder why I cannot add it as an `[alias]`??  `ls-tracked = "! f(){ ls | grep -f <(git ls-files | sed 's/\/.*//g' sort | uniq); }; f"`-> `fatal: bad config file`

Answer (score 6):

`git ls-tree <tree-ish>` is good and all, but I can't figure out how to specify ***the index*** as the `<tree-ish>`. (Although I'm sure there's bound to be some all-caps reference to do just that.)

Anyhow, `ls-files` implicitly works on the index so I might as well use that:

```sh
$ git ls-files | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq
```

This shows files and directories only in the current directory.

Change `cut`'s `-f` argument to control depth.  For instance, `-f-2` (that's *dash* two) shows files and directories up to two levels deep:

```
$ git ls-files | cut -d/ -f-2 | uniq
```

IF you specify the `<path>` argument to `ls-files`, make sure to increase `-f` to accommodate the leading directories:

```
$ git ls-files foo/bar | cut -d/ -f-3 | uniq
```

Comment: You can get a tree for the index with [`git write-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree).

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this is so hard...  but don't get me started on my griping about git.

A variant on jthill's answer seems to be aliasable (hey, I'm a linguist, I have a license to make new words).  The variant is

```
ls -d `git ls-tree HEAD | sed -e "s/^.*\t//"`
```

This uses 'ls' to format the output, so you get color coding (if you use that), etc.  It also works as an alias:

```
alias gitls='ls -d `git ls-tree HEAD | sed -e "s/^.*\t//"`'
```

FWIW, you can also alias the recursive command, so that you used the 'ls' formatting (e.g. if your path+filenames aren't too long, you'll get two column output, color coding of executables, etc.)

```
alias gitls-r='ls `git ls-files`'
```

Comment: Smart trick getting coloring through 'ls'. I personally prefer 'ls -ld', but that's me. Instead of piping through sed, you could use the --name-only (probably new) flag.

Comment: @Uri: right, --name-only is simpler, thanks!  And using -ld is certainly simpler than some of the methods above for getting full info.

Comment: For aliases using `--name-only`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342429/10850071

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), we now limit depth of the tree objects and maximum length of pathnames recorded in tree objects.

That offers a new way to limit depth:

```
git -c core.maxTreeDepth=1 ls-tree -r @
# or
git -c core.maxTreeDepth=1 ls-tree -r HEAD
```

(`@` is short for `HEAD` [since Git 1.8.5, Q4 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871357/6309),
... although it was officially the case only with [Git 2.30, Q1 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375464/6309))

See [commit 4d5693b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d5693ba05ae0d722ad5a6c0e34296caf6be9b74), [commit 7b61bd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b61bd18b13223064db01d89e3b8af106661efd5), [commit 670a1da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/670a1dadc7d98b774cc0f870a4c75f57d1cfa9d4), [commit 1ee7a5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ee7a5c388626d049af61c9909eefe7640a26fc9), [commit f1f63a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1f63a481bcaaa2124b5f0395abec6b457888bf1), [commit be20128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be20128bfa5423503081ba1884e5367c91849d9e), [commit 0fbcaef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fbcaef6b49250eb92b08e70f815962c729d5615), [commit c7cd0e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7cd0e34cd5f62339d4c92e96d2e7dd848dd5a6c), [commit acd13d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acd13d1eec93e714add1b3f94c8c175d6a8171cb), [commit 59c4c7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59c4c7d1cbd23eaade955e61f8f1d5d964a9a727) (31 Aug 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 174dfe4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/174dfe463778680382d32a280ad73bc12e2017d3), 14 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be20128bfa5423503081ba1884e5367c91849d9e):add core.maxTreeDepth config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Most of our tree traversal algorithms use recursion to visit sub-trees.
> For pathologically large trees, this can cause us to run out of stack space and abort in an uncontrolled way.
> Let's put our own limit here so that we can fail gracefully rather than segfaulting.
>
> In similar cases where we recursed along the commit graph, we rewrote the algorithms to avoid recursion and keep any stack data on the heap.
> But the commit graph is meant to grow without bound, whereas it's not an imposition to put a limit on the maximum size of tree we'll handle.
>
> And this has a bonus side effect: coupled with a limit on individual tree entry names, this limits the total size of a path we may encounter.
> This gives us an extra protection against code handling long path names which may suffer from integer overflows in the size (which could then be exploited by malicious trees).
>
> The default of 4096 is set to be much longer than anybody would care about in the real world.
> Even with single-letter interior tree names (like "a/b/c"), such a path is at least 8191 bytes.
> While most operating systems will let you create such a path incrementally, trying to reference the whole thing in a system call (as Git would do when actually trying to access it) will result in ENAMETOOLONG.
> Coupled with the recent fsck.largePathname warning, the maximum total pathname Git will handle is (by default) 16MB.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be20128bfa5423503081ba1884e5367c91849d9e/Documentation/config/core.txt#L739-L744):

> ### `core.maxTreeDepth`
>
> The maximum depth Git is willing to recurse while traversing a
> tree (e.g., "`a/b/cde/f`" has a depth of 4). This is a fail-safe
> to allow Git to abort cleanly, and should not generally need to
> be adjusted. The default is 4096.

Actually, the default is 2048:

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d5693ba05ae0d722ad5a6c0e34296caf6be9b74):lower `core.maxTreeDepth` default to 2048
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> On my Linux system, all of our recursive tree walking algorithms can run up to the 4096 default limit without segfaulting.
> But not all platforms will have stack sizes as generous (nor might even Linux if we kick off a recursive walk within a thread).
>
> In particular, several of the tests added in the previous few commits fail in our Windows CI environment.
> Through some guess-and-check pushing, I found that 3072 is still too much, but 2048 is OK.
>
> These are obviously vague heuristics, and there is nothing to promise that another system might not have trouble at even lower values.
> But it seems unlikely anybody will be too angry about a 2048-depth limit (this is close to the default max-pathname limit on Linux even for a pathological path like "`a/a/a/...`").
> So let's just lower it.
>
> Some alternatives are:
>
> - configure separate defaults for Windows versus other platforms.
> - just skip the tests on Windows.
>   This leaves Windows users with the annoying case that they can be crashed by running out of stack space, but there shouldn't be any security implications (they can't go deep enough to hit integer overflow problems).
>
> Since the original default was arbitrary, it seems less confusing to just lower it, keeping behavior consistent across platforms.

Regarding `git ls-tree`:

> ### [`read_tree()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ee7a5c388626d049af61c9909eefe7640a26fc9): respect `max_allowed_tree_depth`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The `read_tree()` function reads trees recursively (via its `read_tree_at()` helper).
> This can cause it to run out of stack space on very deep trees.
> Let's teach it about the new core.maxTreeDepth option.
>
> The easiest way to demonstrate this is via "`ls-tree -r`", which the test covers.
> Note that I needed a tree depth of ~30k to trigger a segfault on my Linux system, not the 4100 used by our "big" test in t6700.
> However, that test still tells us what we want: that the default 4096 limit is enough to prevent segfaults on all platforms.
> We could bump it, but that increases the cost of the test setup for little gain.
>
> As an interesting side-note: when I originally wrote this patch about 4 years ago, I needed a depth of ~50k to segfault.
> But porting it forward, the number is much lower.
> Seemingly little things like [cf09832](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf0983213c72727c4c7dea51ed9b3b38a2968fbe) (`hash`: add an algo member to struct object_id, 2021-04-26, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aaa3c8065d86e8f25850eb79e90da68d6adcf03f) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49f38e2de47a401fc2b0f4cce38e9f07fb63df48)) (hash: add an algo member to struct `object_id,` 2021-04-26) take it from 32,722 to 29,080.

Comment: Is `@` short for HEAD? 

Comment: @CervEd Yes, since Git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013): see then end of [my answer on "`HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` in Git"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309). I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I have found, believe it or not, is to simply `cd` into the directory you want in your terminal. Running `git ls-files` in `/project/src` will give you results from only that directory, versus running it in `/project`

Not the most technical answer, but hey, it works!

Comment: is simple and effective =), if you don't have any more folders in that folder you cd into, only issue is that if you have folders and other files will march down down those as well

Answer (score -1):

use this [simple bash script](https://gist.github.com/x3ro/6242017) for define subdirectory any level