# How can I make git show a list of the files that are being tracked?

Tags: git

Using command line git, how can I make git show a list of the files that are being tracked in the repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List files in local git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo)

Comment: I believe it is. But it does not feel right to mark this as dup when this has a better answer.

Comment: in a parallel universe, it's uncanny how similar [this question](https://superuser.com/q/429693/571125) is including all the answers, yet each with its own distinctive flair.

Comment: @lindhe: it's almost like the StackExchange obsession with closing duplicates is not 100% sensible

Answer (score 881, accepted):

To list all the files currently being tracked under the branch `master`, use [`ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree):

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```

To list all files that have ever existed (i.e. including deleted files):

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort - | sed '/^$/d'
```

Comment: Use  git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only if you want to list files of the current branch

Comment: Why are directories not listed?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen - `git` does not version directories directly. Instead it stores files and their paths. `ls-tree` will output all the versioned files. To better understand this distinction, try staging an empty directory to `git`. The empty directory will never show up in the staged changes. The only way to version such an empty directory is to actually version a file under the directory. For use cases where you need such an empty placeholder directory in version control, you can create a dummy file under the directory, and version that. I hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: Just note, `ls-tree master` doesn't show the **tracked** files in staging area.

Comment: Is it possible to show just the top-level directory if it includes many subdirectories and files?

Comment: The command to list all _files that ever existed_ does actually only list files until the point HEAD is currently at and it also ignores cases like renames. So I would instead suggest `git log --pretty=format: --name-only --all | sort -u | sed '/^$/d'`

Comment: `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` unfortunately does NOT show tracked files which are in `.gitignore`d folders. This is unfortunate, as I've forcefully added with `git add -f ./UNTRACKED_FOLDER/file_I_need_to_track_anyway` a few files I want to verify are truly tracked.

Comment: UPDATE: Awesome! The answer by @vonbrand *does* work for me! `git ls-files` does show these files.

Comment: This doesn't include recently added but uncommitted files.

Comment: Variation on a theme - all files that have ever been anywhere that result in files currently in the given directory (not very quick but handles renames into the dir and useful for slicing up repos): git ls-files sheetbuilder | xargs --max-lines=1 git log --follow --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq | sed '/^$/d'

Comment: Both works when we have at least one commit.

Answer (score 258):

The files managed by git are shown by `git ls-files`. Check out [its manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

Comment: That seems to only show files at or below the current directory.

Comment: Mind if I edit this to include the relevant sections of the manual page?

Comment: @NathanBasanese perhaps you can add another answer with that information.

Comment: @LyleZ Perhaps this is intended to be in keeping with `ls`...or `ls -R`

Comment: @LyleZ Also, this behavior is the same with `git ls-tree` - it is relative to the `pwd`.

Comment: @LyleZ - I can see files in children folders of the current directory also.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - the OP Question specifically states `"in the repository?"`. As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76797811/22595851), and in `man git-ls-files`, the answer offered here does **not** show the files when you are in the repository itself. It will show files in the working tree or the index - but not in `the repository`.  Where else can you rack up 250+ votes for an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 56):

The accepted answer only shows files in the current directory's tree. To show *all* of the tracked files that have been committed (on the current branch), use

```sh
git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD
```

- `--full-tree` makes the command run as if you were in the repo's root directory.
- `-r` recurses into subdirectories. Combined with `--full-tree`, this gives you all committed, tracked files.
- `--name-only` removes SHA / permission info for when you just want the file paths.
- `HEAD` specifies which branch you want the list of tracked, committed files for. You could change this to `master` or any other branch name, but `HEAD` is the commit you have checked out right now.

This is the method from the accepted answer to the ~duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533413/4880003.

Comment: Nathan, you said "Combined with `--full-tree`, this gives you all committed, tracked files". Does that mean all files that have ever been committed since the beginning of the repo, or is there some cutoff? The currently accept answer includes a `git log` command whose output is a couple thousand lines longer than your command. I'm trying to hunt down large files that were committed almost a decade ago so I can prune them from history.

Answer (score 10):

You might want colored output with this.

I use this one-liner for listing the tracked files and directories in the current directory of the current branch:

```bash
ls --group-directories-first --color=auto -d $(git ls-tree $(git branch | grep \* | cut -d " " -f2) --name-only)
```

You might want to add it as an alias:

```bash
alias gl='ls --group-directories-first --color=auto -d $(git ls-tree $(git branch | grep \* | cut -d " " -f2) --name-only)'
```

If you want to recursively list files:

```bash
'ls' --color=auto -d $(git ls-tree -rt $(git branch | grep \* | cut -d " " -f2) --name-only)
```

And an alias:

```bash
alias glr="'ls' --color=auto -d \$(git ls-tree -rt \$(git branch | grep \\* | cut -d \" \" -f2) --name-only)"
```

Comment: The `glr` alias you provided looked a bit weird so I made a version more consistent with the format of the first alias you provided: `alias glr='ls --color=auto -d $(git ls-tree -rt $(git branch | grep \* | cut -d " " -f2) --name-only)'`. Tested with `git version 2.20.1` on Debian 10.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the existing answers, you can use `tree` to view it a little prettier:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD | tree --fromfile .
```

You probably want to paginate this:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD | tree -C --fromfile . | ${PAGER:-less}
```

This certainly deserves a place as `tree` alias in the git config :)

Answer (score 0):

list files tracked by git, sort by author date

> `git ls-tree -r --name-only main . | while read -r path; do date=$(git log -n1 --format=format:%aI -- "$path"); echo "$date $path"; done | sort -r | cut -c27-`