# Delete git repo and tracked files

Tags: git

I have a git repo that contains the following (simplified):

```
-- .git/
-- data/
   |_ bar.txt
-- src/
   |_ foo.py
-- .gitignore
```

The `.gitignore` ignores only the data directory. So, in this case, `src/foo.py` and `.gitignore` were staged and commited.

I want to remove the `.git` repo AND all files/folders tracked by git without deleting the entire directory as I want to keep the untracked files (ie remove `src/foo.py`, `.gitignore`, and `.git` but keep the `data` folder and it's contents).

I looked at [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) and tried searching stack overflow, but I couldn't seem to find an answer.

**Note:** The above repo is just used as an example, the actual repo I'm concerned with is much more complex and populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a bash shell:

```
for f in $(git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only); do;
    echo rm -rf $f
done
echo rm -rf .git
```

Remove the echo's to make this actually destroy all the files. I don't want anyone pasting this mindlessly and regretting so I'm keeping them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606955/how-can-i-make-git-show-a-list-of-the-files-that-are-being-tracked/15606998), you can run the following command to list (line by line) all files tracked by the current git HEAD.

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only
```

From there it should be as easy as piping the output to `xargs` with the `rm` command:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | xargs rm
```

Then, delete the `.git` folder:

```
rm -rf .git
```

All-in-one command:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | xargs rm && rm -rf .git
```

**Note:** This will only delete files since git doesn't track folders, meaning you'll still have leftover empty directories (in this case, `src/foo.py` would be deleted, but the `src` directory itself would be leftover).

Comment: This will not work if a different branch is currently checked out (you need to replace `master` with `HEAD`)

Comment: @Omer, woops, you're right, that would be correct. Fixed my answer.