# To check whether a local repository is a git repository or not

Tags: git, github, repository

I want to check whether a repository is a git repository or not .
Basically i want to view all the hidden files of a local repo.
I tried ls -a command in terminal of vs code.
but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make git show a list of the files that are being tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606955/how-can-i-make-git-show-a-list-of-the-files-that-are-being-tracked)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how, why, or where you want to check for a git repo, but if you are not in a git repository, any git commands will error and exit with code 128. So you could just run a simple git command like `git status`. If you just want to know as a human, it will say "Not a git repository". If you want to test programmatically in say a bash script, you can test if `$?` is equal to `128`