# What does the "at" @ sign/symbol/character mean in Git?

Tags: git

The at-sign `@` is often used in git to [specify revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) in different
ways. For example,

1. `<ref>@{<date>}` specifies the reference at its state on `<date>`.

   Example: `git diff master@{yesterday} master`.
2. `<ref>@{<n>}` specific the reference at its n<sup>th</sup> prior state.

   Example: `git diff master@{1} master`.
3. `@{-<n>}` specifies the n<sup>th</sup> previously checked-out branch before
   the current one.

   Example: `git checkout @{-5}`.
4. `<ref>@{upstream}` specifies the upstream branch for the reference.

   Example: `git diff master@{upstream} master`.

**However**, the `@` is being used in other ways in git commands too, like

```
git rebase -i @~4
git log @^^..@
```

**What does the at-sign `@` mean in those examples?**

Comment: @sehe that command won't work for msysgit users, msysgit doesn't come with `man`, if they want to use a command to view documentation, they have to use `git rev-parse --help`.

Comment: it's not a command. It's a Moniker using the wellknown "man" namespace :) https://www.google.com/search?q=man+git-rev-parse

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[As of Git version 1.8.5](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.5/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L100-101), the at-sign `@`, without a leading branch/reference name and ordinal `{n}` suffix like `HEAD@{1}` and `master@{1}`, is just a synonym/alias/shortcut for the special Git reference `HEAD`:

> Instead of typing four capital letters "HEAD", you can say "@" now, e.g. "git log @".

So for these commands

```
git rebase -i @~4
git log @^^..@
```

you can simply substitute the *first* occurrence of `@` with `HEAD` (or `head` if using Windows or OS X)

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
git log HEAD^^..HEAD
```

So what does `HEAD` mean? As explained by the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for specifying Git revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions), `HEAD` is a special shortcut reference for the commit that you currently have checked-out as your working copy (or in Git terms, your "working tree"):

> HEAD names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.

You can also read these other Stack Overflow questions on what the special reference `HEAD` means:

1. [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git).
2. [What is git HEAD, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly).

VonC also found interesting information about why `@` was chosen as a shortcut for `head` in [this Stack Overflow answer (the last section at the bottom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/964927#964927).

Note that like it often happens with Git, while `@` is a convenient shortcut, it isn't *always* a valid replacement for `HEAD`. Example:

```
$ git bundle create temp.bundle @
Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Total 25 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

$ git bundle list-heads temp.bundle
c006e049da432677d1a27f0eba661671e0524710 refs/heads/master

$ git bundle create temp.bundle HEAD
Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Total 25 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

$ git bundle list-heads temp.bundle
c006e049da432677d1a27f0eba661671e0524710 HEAD
```

In this case, using `@` is more like a replacement for `master` (the branch that `HEAD` happened to be pointing to) rather than for `HEAD`. If you try to fetch from the resulting bundle later, you'll have to specify the ref you want to fetch (`master`) if you used `@`, and you won't have to to it if you specified `HEAD` explicitly.

Comment: You can even use `@@{1}` as a shortcut for `HEAD@{1}`

Comment: `HEAD` and `@` are not completely interchangeable, e.g. while on a branch `git push origin @:new-branch` fails with ambiguous ref, while `git push origin HEAD:new-branch` works.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that `@` means `HEAD` since Git 1.8.5 (Q3 2013), it... does not *always* work, not before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021),

"`@`" sometimes worked (e.g. "`git push origin @:there` as a part of a refspec element, but "`git push origin @`" did *not* work, which has been corrected.

See [commit 374fbae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/374fbaef3df8f05acf9968fc38c6da72a62bcfc2), [commit e7f80ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7f80eafd1be8c6771ef3e1e389853e18ed7e90b), [commit 12a30a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12a30a3ea65f1d27698927c5a871935f6c1223f9) (25 Nov 2020) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c59b73b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c59b73bef302f4efd0f853f913328aab534b1f1a), 14 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`refspec`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/374fbaef3df8f05acf9968fc38c6da72a62bcfc2): make `@` a synonym of `HEAD`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> Since [commit 9ba89f484e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba89f484e023827eca6ad44baf69af37dac4db3) Git learned how to push to a remote branch using the source `@`, for example:
>
> ```
> git push origin @:master
> ```
>
> However, if the right-hand side is missing, the push fails:
>
> ```
> git push origin @
> ```
>
> It is obvious what is the desired behavior, and allowing the push makes things more consistent.
>
> Additionally, `@:master` now has the same semantics as `HEAD:master`.

---

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2082dbdd315aa4dd3f315545e5b3ab3b3e2d894), teach "[`git checkout -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/65462776c2963b377968e580ace1590238bf79c1/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L278)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--p))</sup> and friends that `@` is a synonym for HEAD.

See [commit 7abc186](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7abc1869e552b80ea35923ae4315cb8bb0b47b64), [commit 5a8ed3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a8ed3fe450caad740b1c236b3f14151f84bed05) (13 Feb 2024) by [Ghanshyam Thakkar (`spectre10`)](https://github.com/spectre10).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6546277](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65462776c2963b377968e580ace1590238bf79c1), 26 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`add-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a8ed3fe450caad740b1c236b3f14151f84bed05): classify '`@`' as a synonym for 'HEAD'
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ghanshyam Thakkar</sup>

> Currently, (restore, checkout, reset) commands correctly take '`@`' as a synonym for 'HEAD'.
>
> However, in patch mode different prompts/messages are given on command line due to patch mode machinery not considering '`@`' to be a synonym for 'HEAD' due to literal string comparison with the word 'HEAD', and therefore assigning `patch_mode_($command)_nothead` and triggering reverse mode (`-R` in `diff-index`).
>
> The `NEEDSWORK` comment suggested comparing commit objects to get around this.
> However, doing so would also take a non-checked out branch pointing to the same commit as HEAD, as HEAD.
> This would cause confusion to the user.
>
> Therefore, after parsing '`@`', replace it with '`HEAD`' as reasonably early as possible.
> This also solves another problem of disparity between '[`git checkout HEAD`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a8ed3fe450caad740b1c236b3f14151f84bed05/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> and '`git checkout @`' (latter detaches at the HEAD commit and the former does not).
>
> Trade-offs:
>
> - Some of the errors would show the revision argument as 'HEAD' when given '`@`'.
>   This should be fine, as most users who probably use '`@`' would be aware that it is a shortcut for 'HEAD' and most probably used to use 'HEAD'.
>   There is also relevant documentation in 'gitrevisions' manpage about '`@`' being the shortcut for 'HEAD'.
>   Also, the simplicity of the solution far outweighs this cost.
> - Consider '`@`' as a shortcut for 'HEAD' even if '`refs/heads/@`' exists at a different commit.
>   Naming a branch '`@`' is an obvious foot-gun and many existing commands already take '`@`' for 'HEAD' even if '`refs/heads/@`' exists at a different commit or does not exist at all (e.g. '[`git log @`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a8ed3fe450caad740b1c236b3f14151f84bed05/Documentation/git-log.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup>, '[`git push origin @`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a8ed3fe450caad740b1c236b3f14151f84bed05/Documentation/git-push.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> etc.).
>   Therefore this is an existing assumption and should not be a problem.