# Undo a git rebase using onto

Tags: git, rebase

I rebased my branch `version2` against master using:

```
git rebase --onto master version1 version2
```

How can I undo this?

To undo it I did `git reflog`

Currently, `git status` (on `version2`) gives me :

```
Your branch and 'origin/version2' have diverged,
and have 2563 and 222 different commits each, respectively.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I want to undo this rebase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you haven't modified the `version2` branch since you rebased it, all you need to do is a hard reset of the branch to its 1st prior position, using `<reference>@{n}` syntax, where `n` is the Nth prior position of the reference:

```
git checkout version2
git reset --hard version2@{1}
```

Comment: You can read more about it in my answer to [What does the “at” @ sign/symbol/character mean in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910096/what-does-the-at-sign-symbol-character-mean-in-git/17910097#17910097), the last section.

Answer (score 17):

A very quick and easy way to undo a `git rebase` is to put the branch labels back.

If you're sure you want to abandon the current `version2` branch tip, you can start with `git reflog` (like you did).  I will include the `rebase` step here too, and I'll leave in a few "real" abbreviated refs:

```
$ git checkout branch
$ git rebase --onto master start-after branch
... rebase output ...
# oops! dag-nab-it! didn't mean to do that!

$ git reflog
<rev..> HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/branch
<rev..> HEAD@{1}: rebase: some commit msg...
05f7dc8 HEAD@{2}: rebase: checkout master
aa4e140 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to branch
```

Here `aa4e140` is where the `HEAD` of the branch was.  This is also available in `ORIG_HEAD`:

```
$ git log -1 --oneline ORIG_HEAD
aa4e140 some commit msg...
```

(use more of the log if you need to, to make sure you're going to the right place.)

If you've done some other git things since the rebase, `ORIG_HEAD` may have moved, but the reflog will have the right value.  If `ORIG_HEAD` and what you see in the reflog agree, you definitely have the right value.  Either way, make sure you have the right value (and that you have no un-saved changes, that `git status` is clean—you can use `git stash` if needed, here).

Also try `git reflog version2`, which will show you the history of the label `version2`.

Now just force the current branch—make sure that's still the one you want changed—to the target commit:

```
$ git branch
... see that you're still on "branch" or "version2" or whatever
$ git reset --hard aa4e140
```

Voila, things are back to exactly the way they were before you ran `git rebase`.

If you have not done anything to change `ORIG_HEAD`, it's even easier than all this:

```
$ git log ORIG_HEAD # make sure that's what you want
...
$ git branch        # make sure you're on `version2`
...
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
HEAD is now at ...
```

but the `reflog` method is more general (works for about a month<sup>1</sup> after the rebase, no matter what you have done in between).

(<sup>1</sup>The time period here is configurable; see [git reflog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) documentation.  The default 30 day expiration is for reflog entries "not reachable from the current tip of the branch", which is usually the case for the old commits from before a rebase.)

---

The key to understanding *why* this works is simple: `git rebase` *keeps your old commits*.  It just *adds new commits to the commit-graph, then moves the label*.  With the label moved, it's harder to see your old commits—they don't show up by default, they're only in the "reflog"—but they are still in there.  Put the label back, and the *new* commits are the ones that don't show up, and the old ones are all back!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation in the last paragraph. None of the other answers I've seen have done that.

Comment: Agree with bunnyhero. resetting rebase made no sense until you understand that nothing is really lost in git, and gitX doesn't show parts of commit tree which are not reachable by ref objects