# Fixing a botched `git rebase`

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-reset

I understand `git rebase` a bit. And I understand `git reflog` and `git reset --hard` a bit, too. But the [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973015/undo-a-git-rebase-using-onto) and [blog posts](http://elegantcode.com/2013/02/16/how-do-i-undo-a-bad-rebase-in-git/) I've tried can't seem to help me fix this error I've made.

I am working on a change to [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette). I was doing as I normally do, squashing my commits into one, when I noticed at some point that I had actually somehow 'attached' a bunch of commits [to my PR](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/pull/845). It [now lists 6 commits](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/pull/845/commits), with my latest one being separate from the others.

I'm unsure if this is what squashing looks like when you squash commits from multiple users, so my first question is: what is going on here? Were they accidentally squashed?

The second question is how might I fix this? Nothing I do seems to work. I `git reset --hard` to before I did any rebases, and it still shows those 6 commits as unpushed commits. Even if I `reset --hard` *all the way to when I cloned the repo*, it still lists those other commits.

What is going on here? Do you have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's the answer (credits go to [cobbweb](https://github.com/cobbweb)):

1. Hard reset your repository entirely
   `git reset --hard origin/master`

   What this does is update your repository to be in the same state as the remote repository. It will also set all of the commits (both the ones you want & the ones you don't want) as **unpushed** commits in the local branch. This is where you want to be.
2. Select **only** the commit that you want
   `git cherry-pick {{ SHA }}`

   where `{{SHA}}` is the commit ID for that thing. It will look something like *344dc098ffle90aaef3*.
3. Force the push and you should be good to go.
   `git push --force`

If you'd like to know more on what's going on here run a google/SO search on each of the things we've done here: hard resets, cherry-picking, and force pushing. You'll find a wealth of information about them.

**Note:** This problem and solution involved working on just the **master** branch. Things might be a bit different if you are dealing with a situation with more than one branch.