# What is @ for in git command?

Tags: git

I came across a git expression, `git show master@{3}` and I have no idea what it's for and how to use it. I get it what is `git show` for but the puzzling part here is the `@{3}`.
In my repo I did try this command, and terminal said `fatal: Log for 'master' only has 1 entries.`, so couldn't figure it out from the message.
Could you anyone explain that for me and why I got this specific error. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `git help revisions` for help.

> `@` alone is a shortcut for `HEAD`.

`HEAD` is explained in the same document:

> HEAD names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.

And the curly brackets are described there, too:

> `@{<n>}`, e.g. `@{1}`
>
> You can use the `@` construct with an empty ref part to get at a reflog entry of
>              the current branch. For example, if you are on branch blabla then `@{1}` means
>              the same as `blabla@{1}`.

So, `@{3}` points to the third prior reflog value from the entry of the current branch.

Comment: If it is related to reflog, then it has no relation to current branch.... just saying.

Comment: @eftshift0: Reformulated.

Comment: Thanks! I just learnt reflog command as well.

Comment: "Thank you" on stackoverflow = upvote / accept ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375464/6309), `@` means HEAD.

But regarding the specific error `fatal: Log for 'master' only has 1 entries.` (specific to this question):

After expiring a reflog and making a single commit, the reflog for the branch would record a single entry that knows both `@{0}` and `@{1}`, but we failed to answer "what commit were we on?" i.e. `@{1}`

That has been fixed with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), so you should not always see that error message.

See [commit 6436a20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6436a20284f33d42103cac93bd82e65bebb31526) (07 Jan 2021), and [commit 95c2a71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c2a71820c8fc2bd333921dee71c35871923716) (06 Jan 2021) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 440acfb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/440acfbe0cec5c2316ef7a706c975143c4902b20), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6436a20284f33d42103cac93bd82e65bebb31526): allow @{n} to work with n-sized reflog
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> This sequence works
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b newbranch
> $ git commit --allow-empty -m one
> $ git show -s newbranch@{1}
> ```
>
> and shows the state that was immediately after the newbranch was created.
>
> But then if you do
>
> ```
> $ git reflog expire --expire=now refs/heads/newbranch
> $ git commit --allow=empty -m two
> $ git show -s newbranch@{1}
> ```
>
> you'd be scolded with
>
> ```
> fatal: log for 'newbranch' only has 1 entries
> ```
>
> While it is true that it has only 1 entry, we have enough information in that single entry that records the transition between the state in which the tip of the branch was pointing at commit 'one' to the new commit 'two' built on it, so we should be able to answer "what object newbranch was pointing at?".
> But we refuse to do so.
>
> Make `@{0}` the special case where we use the new side to look up that entry.
> Otherwise, look up `@{n}` using the old side of the (n-1)th entry of the reflog.

---

The logic to access reflog entries by date and number had ugly corner cases at the boundaries, which have been cleaned up with Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43072b4ca132437f21975ac6acc6b72dc22fd398).

In particular, [6436a20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6436a20284f33d42103cac93bd82e65bebb31526) mentioned above has been partially reverted.

See [commit 5edd126](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5edd12672086c6b6d92147925dda5dd3bca2b658), [commit 755e746](https://github.com/git/git/commit/755e7465c95075989ab9a0d80ad1ec0c79dd1720), [commit aa72e73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa72e73a2e8f0924462aad5a2a45f12c267b1408) (26 Feb 2024) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 74522bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74522bbd98418bf94e918cef2cf911402eca692f), 05 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`get_oid_basic()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/755e7465c95075989ab9a0d80ad1ec0c79dd1720): special-case ref@{n} for oldest reflog entry
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The goal of [6436a20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6436a20284f33d42103cac93bd82e65bebb31526) ("`refs`: allow @{n} to work with n-sized reflog", 2021-01-07, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/440acfbe0cec5c2316ef7a706c975143c4902b20) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6362826a0409539642a5738db61827e5978e2e4)) was that if we have "n" entries in a reflog, we should still be able to resolve `ref@{n}` by looking at the "old" value of the oldest entry.
>
> Commit [6436a20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6436a20284f33d42103cac93bd82e65bebb31526) tried to put the logic into `read_ref_at()` by shifting its idea of "n" by one.
> But we reverted that in the previous commit, since it led to bugs in other callers which cared about the details of the reflog entry we found.
> Instead, let's put the special case into the caller that resolves `@{n}`, as it cares only about the oid.
>
> `read_ref_at()` is even kind enough to return the "old" value from the final reflog; it just returns "1" to signal to us that we ran off the end of the reflog.
> But we can notice in the caller that we read just enough records for that "old" value to be the one we're looking for, and use it.
>
> Note that `read_ref_at()` could notice this case, too, and just return 0. But we don't want to do that, because the caller must be made aware that we only found the oid, not an actual reflog entry (and the call sites in show-branch do care about this).
>
> There is one complication, though.
> When `read_ref_at()` hits a truncated reflog, it will return the "old" value of the oldest entry only if it is not the null oid.
> Otherwise, it actually returns the "new" value from that entry! This bit of fudging is due to [d1a4489](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1a4489a56e2ceac8e7dc9eb277a9f36fec725c5) ("avoid null SHA1 in oldest reflog", 2008-07-08, Git v1.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1a4489a56e2ceac8e7dc9eb277a9f36fec725c5)), where asking for "`ref@{20.years.ago}`" for a ref created recently will produce the initial value as a convenience (even though technically it did not exist 20 years ago).
>
> But this convenience is only useful for time-based cutoffs.
> For count-based cutoffs, `get_oid_basic()` has always simply complained about going too far back:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse HEAD@{20}
> fatal: log for 'HEAD' only has 16 entries
> ```
>
> and we should continue to do so, rather than returning a nonsense value (there's even a test in t1508 already which covers this).
> So let's have the [d1a4489](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1a4489a56e2ceac8e7dc9eb277a9f36fec725c5) code kick in only when doing timestamp-based cutoffs.