# How to get the Git hash of the current working directory?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git hash-object on a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011172/git-hash-object-on-a-directory)

It is said that the Git hash is a SHA-1 hash of all the files that are being tracked in that commit.  It seems that we can see the hash value of the HEAD by using `git rev-parse HEAD`, but is there a way to see the hash value of the current working directory? (without doing a commit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because the commit ID is hashed from information based on the commit itself, such as the timestamp, description, and author names (in addition to the contents of the tree).

Comment: However, you can calculate the tree ID.