# How to get the tree hash for a given directory name?

Tags: git, git-notes

I'd like to attach a note to a tree object. However, in order to do so I first need to know the tree object's hash. For a given directory name that's part of my repository, how do I get its belonging tree object's hash in order to attach a note to it?

From reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6011324/1127485) I understand I could use

```
git cat-file -p master^{tree}
```

to list the root tree's contents, but I'd still have to grep the output for the directory name, and follow nested tree objects recursively to get the tree object's hash for a directory deeper in the hierarchy.

Basically, I'm looking for the implementation of a fictional `get-tree-hash.sh` script. If called like

```
get-tree-hash.sh path/to/directory/in/my/git/repo
```

it should output

```
The hash for the "repo" tree inside "path/to/directory/in/my/git" is:
92a68a2f5560fa7080393b633e2afd1d5271deef
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:path/to/directory/in/my/git
```

To print only the hash. So you don't need `cut` or `awk` to extract it.

Comment: That's nicer indeed. Details about this syntax are documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememREADMEememmasterREADMEem).

Answer (score 6):

Just figured it out myself,

```
git ls-tree HEAD -- path/to/directory/in/my/git | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -f1
```

does what I want.

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer  you can also use `ls-files -s` as well

Comment: How does `-s` help here? I'm not interested in staged content.

Comment: Agree , i  misunderstood you first.

Comment: `... | awk '{print $3}'` is a bit less clumsy

Comment: This answer was useful to me over the rev-parse one because it works with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
git ls-tree HEAD -- path/to/directory/in/my/git | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -f1
```

You can use the new format option (Git 2.36+ only, Q2 2022):

```
git ls-tree <tree-ish> --format='%x09'
```

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git ls-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1041d58b4d9c587b2b6c76c3dfb14fbe78ccf196/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree))</sup> learns `--oid-only` option, similar to "`--name-only`", and [more generalized "`--format`" option](https://lore.kernel.org/git/cb717d08be87e3239117c6c667cb32caabaad33d.1646390152.git.dyroneteng@gmail.com/).

See [commit 22184af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22184af2cb89f74b7245c77f1c3c10dae6098bcf) (23 Mar 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 9c4d58f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c4d58ff2c385f49585197c8650356955e1fa02e), [commit 0f88783](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f8878359207191195867ebd499abba3710f9f4b), [commit 455923e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/455923e0a152420054ad74f1af36336d5fa7be75), [commit e815171](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e81517155e0370ae5433d256046ab287bb10d04d), [commit 132ceda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/132ceda40f5fe6e53ff7189a941f7e77a165cb7e), [commit 26f6d4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26f6d4d5a015ae95b0818140b6edf297e78e4e67), [commit 82e69b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82e69b0cb5efff33f9359aa0141b05c93001157e), [commit 4e4566f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e4566f67e9433b7b0f475c4f16e1fe77fb527f4), [commit a53343e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a53343e0fd72ee871aef994bf1352be320dbf710) (23 Mar 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit cab851c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cab851c2f8c190bed93719ca8c712fdfcc3c7182), [commit 315f22c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/315f22c853c08b1f3473fc50985d76618f31ebd0), [commit f6b224d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6b224d5ebfe9fcf58ef34eddea68d9fb4384d50), [commit 87af0dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87af0ddf5f311e9b6e361daaa7fd591a230261a0), [commit 889f783](https://github.com/git/git/commit/889f78383eb1e93663ad38a231607e04a1593713) (23 Mar 2022) by [Teng Long (`dyrone`)](https://github.com/dyrone).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1041d58](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1041d58b4d9c587b2b6c76c3dfb14fbe78ccf196), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`ls-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/455923e0a152420054ad74f1af36336d5fa7be75): introduce "`--format`" option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Teng Long</sup>

> Add a `--format` option to `ls-tree`.
> It has an existing default output, and then `--long` and `--name-only` options to emit the default output along with the objectsize and, or to only emit object paths.
>
> Rather than add `--type-only`, `--object-only` etc.
> we can just support a `--format` using a `strbuf_expand()` similar to "for-each-ref --format".
> We might still add such options in the future for convenience.
>
> The `--format` implementation is slower than the existing code, but this change does not cause any performance regressions.
> We'll leave the existing `show_tree()` unchanged, and only run `show_tree_fmt()` in if a `--format` different than the hardcoded built-in ones corresponding to the existing modes is provided.
>
> I.e.
> something like the "--long" output would be much slower with this, mainly due to how we need to allocate various things to do with [`quote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/455923e0a152420054ad74f1af36336d5fa7be75/quote.c) instead of spewing the output directly to stdout.
>
> The new option of '--format' comes from Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmasonn's idea and suggestion, this commit makes modifications in terms of the original [discussion on community](https://public-inbox.org/git/RFC-patch-6.7-eac299f06ff-20211217T131635Z-avarab@gmail.com/).
>
> In [that thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/RFC-patch-6.7-eac299f06ff-20211217T131635Z-avarab@gmail.com/), there was a `"GIT_TEST_LS_TREE_FORMAT_BACKEND"` variable to ensure that we had test coverage for passing tests that would otherwise use `show_tree()` through `show_tree_fmt()`, and thus that the formatting mechanism could handle all the same cases as the non-formatting options.
>
> Somewhere in subsequent re-rolls of that we seem to have drifted away from what the goal of these tests should be.
> We're trying to ensure correctness of `show_tree_fmt()`.
> We can't tell if we "hit [the] fast-path" here, and instead of having an explicit test for that, we can just add it to something our `"test_ls_tree_format"` tests for.
>
> Here is the statistics about performance tests:
>
> **Default format (hitten the builtin formats)**:
>
> ```
> "git ls-tree <tree-ish>" vs "--format='%(mode) %(type) %(object)%x09%(file)'"
>
> $hyperfine --warmup=10 "/opt/git/master/bin/git ls-tree -r HEAD"
> Benchmark 1: /opt/git/master/bin/git ls-tree -r HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):     105.2 ms ±   3.3 ms    [User: 84.3 ms, System: 20.8 ms]
> Range (min … max):    99.2 ms … 113.2 ms    28 runs
>
> $hyperfine --warmup=10 "/opt/git/ls-tree-oid-only/bin/git ls-tree -r --format='%(mode) %(type) %(object)%x09%(file)'  HEAD"
> Benchmark 1: /opt/git/ls-tree-oid-only/bin/git ls-tree -r --format='%(mode) %(type) %(object)%x09%(file)'  HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):     106.4 ms ±   2.7 ms    [User: 86.1 ms, System: 20.2 ms]
> Range (min … max):   100.2 ms … 110.5 ms    29 runs
> ```
>
> **Default format includes object size (hitten the builtin formats)**:
>
> ```
> "git ls-tree -l <tree-ish>" vs "--format='%(mode) %(type) %(object) %(size:padded)%x09%(file)'"
>
> $hyperfine --warmup=10 "/opt/git/master/bin/git ls-tree -r -l HEAD"
> Benchmark 1: /opt/git/master/bin/git ls-tree -r -l HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):     335.1 ms ±   6.5 ms    [User: 304.6 ms, System: 30.4 ms]
> Range (min … max):   327.5 ms … 348.4 ms    10 runs
>
> $hyperfine --warmup=10 "/opt/git/ls-tree-oid-only/bin/git ls-tree -r --format='%(mode) %(type) %(object) %(size:padded)%x09%(file)'  HEAD"
> Benchmark 1: /opt/git/ls-tree-oid-only/bin/git ls-tree -r --format='%(mode) %(type) %(object) %(size:padded)%x09%(file)'  HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):     337.2 ms ±   8.2 ms    [User: 309.2 ms, System: 27.9 ms]
> Range (min … max):   328.8 ms … 349.4 ms    10 runs
> ```

`git ls-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/455923e0a152420054ad74f1af36336d5fa7be75/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L77-L86):

> ### `--format=<format>`
>
> A string that interpolates `%(fieldname)` from the result
> being shown.
>
> It also interpolates `%%` to `%`, and
> `%xx` where `xx` are hex digits interpolates to character
> with hex code `xx`; for example `%00` interpolates to
> `\0` (NUL), `%09` to `\t` (TAB) and `%0a` to `\n` (LF).
>
> When specified, `--format` cannot be combined with other
> format-altering options, including `--long`, `--name-only`
> and `--object-only`.

`git ls-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/455923e0a152420054ad74f1af36336d5fa7be75/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L95-L108):

> The output format of `ls-tree` is determined by either the `--format`
> option, or other format-altering options such as `--name-only` etc.
> (see `--format` above).
>
> The use of certain `--format` directives is equivalent to using those
> options, but invoking the full formatting machinery can be slower than
> using an appropriate formatting option.
>
> In cases where the `--format` would exactly map to an existing option
> `ls-tree` will use the appropriate faster path. Thus the default format
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> %(objectmode) %(objecttype) %(objectname)%x09%(path)
> ```

`git ls-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/455923e0a152420054ad74f1af36336d5fa7be75/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L126-L153):

> Customized format:
>
> It is possible to print in a custom format by using the `--format` option,
> which is able to interpolate different fields using a `%(fieldname)` notation.
> For example, if you only care about the "`objectname`" and "`path`" fields, you
> can execute with a specific "`--format`" like
>
> ```
> git ls-tree --format='%(objectname) %(path)' <tree-ish>
> ```
>
> ### FIELD NAMES
>
> Various values from structured fields can be used to interpolate
> into the resulting output. For each outputing line, the following
> names can be used:
>
> ### `objectmode`
>
> The mode of the object.
>
> ### `objecttype`
>
> The type of the object (`blob` or `tree`).
>
> ### `objectname`
>
> The name of the object.
>
> ### `objectsize[:padded]`
>
> The size of the object ("`-`" if it's a tree).
> It also supports a padded format of size with "%(size:padded)".
>
> ### `path`
>
> The pathname of the object.

---

Warning: "[`git ls-tree --format=%(path) %(path)' $tree $path`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8a40af9cabe2efbb830bf90c864ffda3136926ba/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L86)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree#Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup>" showed the path *three* times, which has been corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit c388fcd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c388fcda9943c0cf46960787041a1ff3bcf5e833), [commit 16fb5c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16fb5c54bd91c9714e12c6d742e5a6fd81459b71) (14 Jan 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8a40af9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a40af9cabe2efbb830bf90c864ffda3136926ba), 23 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ls-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16fb5c54bd91c9714e12c6d742e5a6fd81459b71): fix expansion of repeated %(path)
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> `expand_show_tree()` borrows the base `strbuf` given to us by `read_tree()` to build the full path of the current entry when handling `%(path)`.
> Only its indirect caller, `show_tree_fmt()`, removes the added entry name.
> That works fine as long as `%(path)` is only included once in the format string, but accumulates duplicates if it's repeated:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-tree --format='%(path) %(path) %(path)' HEAD M*
> Makefile MakefileMakefile MakefileMakefileMakefile
> ```
>
> Reset the length after each use to get the same expansion every time; here's the behavior with this patch:
>
> ```
> $ ./git ls-tree --format='%(path) %(path) %(path)' HEAD M*
> Makefile Makefile Makefile
> ```

---

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) update the documentation for the `%x` format placeholder.

See [commit 3744ffc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b) (15 Jun 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e0e8a2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0e8a2dfa05d66562688804ec38939d8bb56a8fd), 22 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ls-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b): fix documentation of `%x` format placeholder
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [`ls-tree --format`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L86)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree#Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup> expands %x followed by two hexadecimal digits to the character indicated by that hexadecimal number, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-tree --format=%x41 HEAD | head -1
> A
> ```
>
> It rejects % followed by a hexadecimal digit, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-tree --format=%41 HEAD | head -1
> fatal: bad ls-tree format: element '41' does not start with '('
> ```
>
> This functionality is provided by `strbuf_expand_literal_cb()`, which has not been changed since it was factored out by [fd2015b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd2015b323d283c73346d70d2285a927650bb60a) ("`strbuf`: separate callback for `strbuf_expand`:ing literals", 2019-01-28, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42977bf5c7306e4c2dded5353f39cf087cf23a1f) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5)).
>
> Adjust the documentation accordingly.

`git ls-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L89-L91):

> `%xNN` where `NN` are hex digits interpolates to character
> with hex code `NN`; for example `%x00` interpolates to
> `\0` (NUL), `%x09` to `\t` (TAB) and `%x0a` to `\n` (LF).

Comment: Note: [using Git 2.37 is preferable](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d232d38bde689fb04161824d1e494617b3f8082).