# Is there a tool that can be used to detect which files changed in large folders?

Tags: git, binaryfiles, onedrive, large-data

I have a large collection of photos (several TBs of data) that I have stored in OneDrive and synced to my local SSD. Due to the storage requirements, I do not really have a backup but just hope that OneDrive keeps my files save. However, I am a bit afraid that, due to some error in OneDrive, OneDrive deletes some photos and syncs these deletions to my local copy. Or maybe I accidently delete some subfolders and do not notice until it is too late. So I would like to have a tool that detects if some files changed (only if, not actually see a diff of the changes). I used to use git for that, but it

- at least doubles my storage requirements since it has to keep a copy of all of the files
- is quite slow for these large amounts of binary data

Since `git diff` is basically useless for binary files, I would be content with a tool like `git status` which just lists which files have been changed, added or deleted. This should be possible by simply storing hashes, not full file contents. Of course, `git` has the advantage that it can restore the deleted files, but I hope that, if I detect that a file is missing, I can restore it from Windows' or OneDrive's recycle bin.

Comment: You can [compute the git tree hash id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011172/how-to-compute-the-git-hash-object-of-a-directory) for the whole directory and compare that. No need to store the whole content in git. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730660/compute-git-hash-of-file-or-directory-outside-of-git-repository) might give some pointers. It seems calculating the tree hash outside of a git repository is hard, but you could probably create one temporarily for this task only. Come to think of it: maybe just storing the result of `git ls-files` is sufficient.

Comment: I personally would avoid most of the OneDrive-type systems here and use a snapshot-driven file system like ZFS to store the images. Stored on a NAS box, with offsite backups in say an S3 bucket, the files would be pretty safe.