# Getting the current git hash of a library from an Airflow Worker

Tags: python, git, airflow

I have a library `mylib` that I want to get the current git hash for logging purposes when I run an Airflow Worker via the `PythonOperator`, [I know several methods to get the latest git hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989858/get-the-current-git-hash-in-a-python-script), [the main issue is I don't know where the directory will be and I'll likely be running it out of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730660/compute-git-hash-of-file-or-directory-outside-of-git-repository).
The workers themselves can all vary (docker, ec2, gke, kubenetes) but the source python library `mylib` would always be installed via a `pip install git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/user/mylib.git@{version}` command. Is there a generic way I can get the git hash for `mylib` on any Airflow worker since the directory where `mylib` is installed will change across my Airflow Workers?

Comment: Unless you know where the Git repository is or have saved the commit hash ID somewhere, no, you can't do that. Your best bet is *probably* to make release versions that store the version information you wish to report in your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install a package from git, you can get the git hash by calling `pip freeze`, for example:

```bash
$ pip install git+https://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git#egg=httpie
$ pip freeze | grep httpie
> httpie @ git+https://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git@621042a0486ceb3afaf47a013c4f2eee4edc1a1d
```

And here is [the commit hash](https://github.com/httpie/httpie/commit/621042a0486ceb3afaf47a013c4f2eee4edc1a1d) on github.

So you can call the command in python and parse the result to get the hash:

```py
import subprocess
hash = subprocess.getoutput("pip freeze | grep <your package name>").split("@")[-1]
```

Comment: I'll try to make my question more clear because this doesn't answer anything

Comment: I just updated my answer, can you test it?